# ionic google places issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

this worked before few days ago after upgrade to v15 angular and install cap http plugin this start...

this the error:
I/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/src_app_pages_drive-view_drive-view_module_ts.js - Line 901 - Msg: updateDestinationSearchResults Called
I/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/src_app_pages_drive-view_drive-view_module_ts.js - Line 902 - Msg: [object CustomEvent]
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/vendor.js - Line 69056 - Msg: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

this part of my code:

```
updateDestinationSearchResults(event) {
    console.log('updateDestinationSearchResults Called');
    console.log(event);

    this.pickUpAutoCompleteItems = [];
    this.destinationAutoCompleteItems = [];

    if (this.destinationAutoComplete.input === '') {
      this.clearResult('d');
      return;
    }

    if (event.detail == null || event.detail.srcElement.value === '') {
      this.clearResult('d');
      return;
    }

    this.GoogleAutocomplete.getPlacePredictions({ input: event.detail.srcElement.value },
      (predictions, status) => {
        console.log(predictions);
        this.destinationAutoCompleteItems = [];
        this.zone.run(() => {
          if (predictions !== null) {
            predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
              this.destinationAutoCompleteItems.push(prediction);
            });
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

thanks.

to find near places (use google places) of the location I typing

Comment: still didn't found any answer... can help me please?